# how to fix fatal error .cpp file on android

Tags: android, c++, opencv

i want to code some vehicle detection on android with openCV. i got some error on jni folder.

at first time, i got vehicledetection.cpp on my jni folder and i create android.mk with local_src_files := vehicledetection.cpp and local_module := mixed_sample. there is no problem with that, but after i want to replace vehicledetection.cpp into demo.cpp.

i got some error on demo.cpp with :

"jni/vehicledetection.cpp:5:44: fatal error: package_bgs/FrameDifferenceBGS.h: no such file or directory compilation terminated" and "make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mixed_sample/vehicledetection.o] Error 1".

although i change my android.mk local_src_files := vehicledetection.cpp into demo.cpp. and i try to replace all the content in demo.cpp into vehicledetection.cpp but it still give the same error. can anybody help me fix this problem?

Comment: Have You eradicated all generated files from the time when You used the previous name?

Comment: what is eradicated all generated files? which kind of files?
thanks before

Comment: FrameDifferenceBGS.h: no such file . - so ?

Answer (score 0):

Try "cleaning" the project from Your IDE or remove contents of bin and gen directories. Your problem is probably caused by leftovers form the previous version of Your application.